# how to use sleuth in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

A strange problem occured when I integrated sleuth into my applications.

here is the maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

version of the springboot parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

version of the spring cloud dependency

```
Hoxton.SR8
```

After integrating the sleuth, my redisson will never normal again!
First thing is that application will be stuck by redisson and cannot start up.
But I have 9 applications using the same redisson component, only one is down showing like this.

```
2021-04-09 13:23:59.081 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-4] INFO  | ConnectionPool.java:167 |o.r.c.pool.MasterConnectionPool |1 connections initialized for /192.168.24.201:16379
2021-04-09 13:23:59.081 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-5] INFO  | ConnectionPool.java:167 |o.r.c.p.MasterPubSubConnectionPool |1 connections initialized for /192.168.24.201:16379
2021-04-09 13:23:59.085 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:74 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |DNS monitoring enabled; Current masters: {redis://192.168.24.201:16379=/192.168.24.201:16379}, slaves: {}
2021-04-09 13:23:59.417 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=1, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:50:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:02.250 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:04.086 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-7] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:101 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Request sent to resolve ip address for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:04.089 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-6] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:116 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Resolved ip: /192.168.24.201 for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:04.411 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:04.419 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:09.091 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-8] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:101 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Request sent to resolve ip address for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:09.092 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-6] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:116 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Resolved ip: /192.168.24.201 for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:09.418 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:09.426 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:10.031 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:10.044 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | RedisConnectionUtils.java:131 |o.s.d.r.core.RedisConnectionUtils |Opening RedisConnection
2021-04-09 13:24:10.065 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | RedisClient.java:263 |io.lettuce.core.RedisClient |Trying to get a Redis connection for: RedisURI [host='192.168.24.201', port=16379]
2021-04-09 13:24:10.250 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | EpollProvider.java:70 |io.lettuce.core.EpollProvider |Starting without optional epoll library
2021-04-09 13:24:10.252 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | KqueueProvider.java:72 |io.lettuce.core.KqueueProvider |Starting without optional kqueue library
2021-04-09 13:24:10.254 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.java:85 |i.l.c.r.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider |Allocating executor io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup
2021-04-09 13:24:10.254 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.java:196 |i.l.c.r.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider |Creating executor io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup
2021-04-09 13:24:10.261 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.java:98 |i.l.c.r.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider |Adding reference to io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup@3791160a, existing ref count 0
2021-04-09 13:24:10.279 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | RedisClient.java:771 |io.lettuce.core.RedisClient |Resolved SocketAddress 192.168.24.201:16379 using RedisURI [host='192.168.24.201', port=16379]
2021-04-09 13:24:10.280 [web-resource-center,,,] [main] DEBUG | AbstractRedisClient.java:312 |io.lettuce.core.RedisClient |Connecting to Redis at 192.168.24.201:16379
2021-04-09 13:24:10.309 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | CommandHandler.java:181 |i.l.core.protocol.CommandHandler |[channel=0xa3b9507c, [id: 0xd9465333] (inactive), chid=0x1] channelRegistered()
2021-04-09 13:24:10.317 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | CommandHandler.java:294 |i.l.core.protocol.CommandHandler |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, chid=0x1] channelActive()
2021-04-09 13:24:10.318 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | DefaultEndpoint.java:421 |i.l.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, epid=0x1] activateEndpointAndExecuteBufferedCommands 0 command(s) buffered
2021-04-09 13:24:10.319 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | DefaultEndpoint.java:426 |i.l.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, epid=0x1] activating endpoint
2021-04-09 13:24:10.319 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | DefaultEndpoint.java:508 |i.l.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, epid=0x1] flushCommands()
2021-04-09 13:24:10.319 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | DefaultEndpoint.java:523 |i.l.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, epid=0x1] flushCommands() Flushing 0 commands
2021-04-09 13:24:10.320 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | ConnectionWatchdog.java:180 |i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, last known addr=/192.168.24.201:16379] channelActive()
2021-04-09 13:24:10.321 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | CommandHandler.java:308 |i.l.core.protocol.CommandHandler |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, chid=0x1] channelActive() done
2021-04-09 13:24:10.322 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | AbstractRedisClient.java:359 |io.lettuce.core.RedisClient |Connecting to Redis at 192.168.24.201:16379: Success
2021-04-09 13:24:10.328 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | RedisChannelHandler.java:179 |io.lettuce.core.RedisChannelHandler |dispatching command AsyncCommand [type=AUTH, output=StatusOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand]
2021-04-09 13:24:10.335 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | DefaultEndpoint.java:389 |i.l.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, epid=0x1] write() writeAndFlush command TracedCommand [type=AUTH, output=StatusOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand]
2021-04-09 13:24:10.335 [web-resource-center,,,] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-7-1] DEBUG | CommandHandler.java:374 |i.l.core.protocol.CommandHandler |[channel=0xa3b9507c, /192.168.23.110:52384 -> /192.168.24.201:16379, chid=0x1] write(ctx, TracedCommand [type=AUTH, output=StatusOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand], promise)
2021-04-09 13:24:14.092 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-9] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:101 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Request sent to resolve ip address for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:14.093 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-6] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:116 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Resolved ip: /192.168.24.201 for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:19.095 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-10] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:101 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Request sent to resolve ip address for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:19.096 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-6] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:116 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Resolved ip: /192.168.24.201 for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:20.107 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-2] DEBUG | RedisExecutor.java:632 |org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor |connection released for command null and params null from slot NodeSource [slot=null, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=MasterSlaveEntry [masterEntry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:49:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=1, freeConnectionsCounter=value:10:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0]]] using connection RedisConnection@2083200128 [redisClient=[addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379], channel=[id: 0x9f49e9d3, L:/192.168.23.110:52352 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379], currentCommand=null]
2021-04-09 13:24:24.098 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-11] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:101 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Request sent to resolve ip address for master host: 192.168.24.201
2021-04-09 13:24:24.099 [web-resource-center,,,] [redisson-netty-4-6] DEBUG | DNSMonitor.java:116 |org.redisson.connection.DNSMonitor |Resolved ip: /192.168.24.201 for master host: 192.168.24.201
```

It will never start up!

After setting sleuth.redis.enabled=false, the problem solved but came to another with error log like this.

Though error exists, it seems that redisson still works in a right way like nothing happened.

```
2021-04-09 11:54:50.714 [web-task-center,,,] [redisson-timer-6-1] ERROR | PingConnectionHandler.java:89 |o.r.c.handler.PingConnectionHandler |Unable to send PING command over channel: [id: 0xbbb8da57, L:/192.168.23.110:58621 - R:/192.168.24.201:16379]
org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command execution timeout for command: (PING), params: [], Redis client: [addr=redis://192.168.24.201:16379]
    at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.lambda$async$1(RedisConnection.java:207)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:672)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:747)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:472)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, there are problems in feign too.

my feign client which is never crashed ever before integrating the sleuth:

```
@PostMapping("/producer/message/sendMessage")
Boolean sendMessage(@RequestBody(required = true) JSONObject jsonObject) throws Exception;
```

invoking method is shown below

```
try {
        JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
        msg.put("name", "gateway");
        msg.put("data", requestString);
        messageProducerApi.sendMessage(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage().contains("Load balancer does not have available server for client")) {
            log.error("service web-message-center not found，please wait a moment。");
        } else {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the exception will be thrown like this:

```
feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Boolean] and content type [application/xml;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.decode(AsyncResponseHandler.java:119)
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:87)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.infiai.webgateway.aop.WhitelistCountingAop.lambda$doAround$0(WhitelistCountingAop.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Boolean] and content type [application/xml;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder.decode(SpringDecoder.java:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder.decode(ResponseEntityDecoder.java:62)
    at feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder.decode(OptionalDecoder.java:36)
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.decode(AsyncResponseHandler.java:115)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:284)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1468)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$BooleanDeserializer._parseBoolean(NumberDeserializers.java:267)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$BooleanDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$BooleanDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3487)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:273)
    ... 13 more
```

this feignclient is called by a service which is **not** under sleuth controll. the calling order is shown below:
A(feignclient controller)
B(invoking method in D's AOP aspect)
C(out side service)
D(my service)

user--> D --> B --> C --> B --> A --> A successful processed and return true --> exception occured

I'm pretty sure that all the problems were came from sleuth integration. But I have no idea how to fix this.
Is that the version of sleuth which I use is incorrect so lead to so many problems?

Comment: The first thing came to my ming is could you please try not to define dependency versions (e.g.: sleuth) and use the BOM?
Will everything go back to normal if you remove the sleuth dependency?

Comment: @JonatanIvanov yes, once I removed the sleuth dependency, everything was back to normal. It seems that there is a filter in sleuth that changed my response content type. But I can't find where it is...